# Order missing while converting to ArrayList from HashSet

Tags: java, android, arraylist, set, hashset

I am working to convert `ArrayList` to `HashSet`and then `HashSet` to `ArrayList.` It's working perfectly. I have passed an `ArrayList` in an order. But i am getting result in different order.
How to solve this?

```
public void saveAlbumList(ArrayList<String> values) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(values);
        pref_selected_photos.edit().putStringSet("AlbumList", set).commit();
    }

public ArrayList<String> getAlbumList() {
    ArrayList<String> pathList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Set<String> set = pref_selected_photos.getStringSet("AlbumList",
                null);
        if (set != null && set.size() > 0) {
            pathList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pathList;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can  you tell me what is the need to `convert ArrayList to HashSet and vice versa` ?? Just to Save it in SharedPreference ???

Comment: Yes. I want to save it in SharedPreference.

Comment: Then why are you using ArrayList..Directly switch to HashSet.. Otherwise I can guide you to save ArrayList

Comment: Yes. You are right. We have different ways to save ArrayList in preferences. But we must know why this happening and How to solve this?

Comment: You question made ma concept clear :) And  i also get to learn something new :)

Comment: That's great food for hungry birds to learn new concept

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63163/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-selva-pollachi).

Answer (score 3):

As @dreamCoder mentioned You need to use `LinkedHashSet`

> Don't directly assign the values to `LinkedHashSet`. Iterate the `ArrayList` and add it

Change your method code :

```
public void saveAlbumList(ArrayList<String> values) {
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet();
        for(String name : values){
            set.add(name);
        }
        pref_selected_photos.edit().putStringSet("AlbumList", set).commit();
    }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: It's working until close the application. Once i closed and open the application, order is changed again.

Comment: let me check and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` does not preserve the element addition order. First it computes the object hash code that should stay constant but is difficult to predict, and then uses it to select a bucket that is a list of objects that have had the same bucket selected. As an `Iterator` just iterates over all buckets, the iteration order is largely unpredictable.

Use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead if you need to preserve the order. However `LinkedHashSet` maintains an additional linked list so needs more resources.

Comment: refer this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: It's working until close the application. Once i closed and open the application, order is changed again.

Comment: First check order in `ArrayList` then iterate it and add it in `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: i checked well. It's not working once i closed and open the application

Comment: Strange ... i am getting right order...can you please share your code?